# SQL Server - filtering tables by name with GUI

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have createda Linked Server on server X to be able to query server Y.

there is a possibility to filter the tabels on server Y by name from server X Linked server GUI?

this is how it is look like now, the option "filter" doesn't exists:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SSMS does not provide filtering option at this level. You could use simple SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [linked_server].[database_name].sys.tables
WHERE [name] LIKE 'table_name'
  AND [schema_id] = SCHEMA_ID('dbo');
```

---

There is GUI option though not by using filtering:

View -> Object Explorer Details (F7) and search box

[image]

[image]

As you can see `filter icon` is inactive but `Search` is working.